# Keystroke to maximize along the vertical only in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

You can maximize a window in Windows 7 using the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> keystroke. You can also maximize the window along the vertical by double-clicking the upper or lower bits of the window chrome of a "normal" window. But is there a keystroke to achieve the vertical maximize?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>

The whole list of [Windows keyboard shortcuts](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts).

Answer (score 2):

The official and complete list of Windows shortcuts can be found on the [Microsoft support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts). Alas, for what it excels at in information, it lacks in SEO.

So yeah, <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>, but possibly so much more!

Enjoy responsibly!

Comment: Why did you duplicate previous answer?

Comment: The point of my answer was to point to the complete & official list of Windows keyboard shortcut. The link in the voted answer is on a site that's no longer available and, having read it a couple of months ago, it's rather incomplete as far as Windows 10 goes.