# Maximize window horizontally in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

In Windows 10, the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> maximizes the active window [vertically](https://superuser.com/a/180007/6581), that is, resizes the window such that the top and bottom edges of the window align with the top and bottom edges of the monitor where the window is located.

Is there a keyboard shortcut which similarly maximizes the active window *horizontally* (only)?

If not, is there any other easier way to accomplish this task than manually left-click-dragging the left and right edges of the active window to the edges of the current monitor?

Comment: I edited your question referencing Ctrl+Win+Up to correct Win+Shift+Up.  But I don't think there is similar keyboard shortcut for horizontal stretch.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me about the vertical maximization shortcut. I'd been wanting to use it for a long time. It's some effort to hunt down a few pixels to doubleclick.

Answer (score 5):

As you can see in the [Microsoft Windows 10 Keyboard Shortcuts](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts) cheat-sheet, maximizing the Windows horizontally is not a thing.

You can maximize it to the whole screen or vertically.